With regard to desktop (skype) files, has the way wm-class changed starting with 24.04 (or at least after 22.04)?
I am having trouble getting an installation of Skype to handle the incons in the DASH correctly. Currently (24.04) it will always show a gear icon for the skype executable even if its correct icon is already available in the DASH. For 22.04 it worked correctly. So has something changed?
I am using Wayland.
Skype is a snap.
App Centre is a snap.
I have used the application App Centre as a reference to compare with skype desktop files. The first thing I notice is that StartupWMClass=Skype doesn't appear in the App Centre desktop file whereas it does in the skype offering.
I also notice that xprop does not work for 'App Centre' but does for skype. (But does work if I login using Xorg instead). I as sure this means something. (Does it mean that the desktop apps doesn't work for X only targets?) Incidentally, xprop shows skype wm-class as Skype
Using the gnomes’s integrated debugger lg (run through ALT F2 lg -> select Windows) it shows Skype as untracked which, I think, is a manifestation of the fault?
Also using the gnomes’s integrated debugger it shows (select the line above the wm-class and read the top line) App Centre as a wayland application and skype as a xwayland application. This suggests it is only xwayland applications that do not work correctly.
Note the following bug reports: -
https://github.com/slint-ui/slint/issues/2579
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/34928
There is also some nice links to show how desktop files are generated so that the source desktop file stays in touch with the executable (so relevant to this question). I have included the link, again, below.
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/ApplicationBased
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/recognized-keys.html
(Note: the links, above, point to further bug links)
I have tried swapping out the Exec line from skype to App Centre (commenting out the original) and it starts failing. Adding the StartupWMClass=Skype made no difference. It makes me thing that last bit doesn't function at all any more.
Note skype and App Centre are both snaps so I though the best batch for comparison.
So is there now another way that apps are wm-class registered?

I'm confused by the references to App Centre:  "StartupWMClass=Skype doesn't appear in the App Centre desktop file": Why do you think the .desktop file for App Centre would have any references to Skype at all? "swapping out the Exec line from skype to App Centre" ... what did you think would happen here? "xprop does not work for 'App Centre' but does for skype" .. would indicate that you're using Wayland, and Skype is using XWayland whereas App Centre supports Wayland. "Does it mean that the desktop apps doesn't work for X only targets?" I don't understand this question either.

I used a copy of the 'App Centre' desktop file to investigate the problem with the 'Skype' desktop file. So, starting from a working 'App Centre' I attempted to make minimal changes to make it run the 'Skype' executable, hopefully with the correct icon effects.

That's ... even less clear. If you started from a copy of the 'App Centre' desktop file and were editing it to make it run Skype, then wouldn't you be changing the Exec line from App Centre to skype instead of the other way around?

I was not aware there is a Wayland and an XWayland - hence I referred to latter as just X. So it seems I should modify my question by changing X to XWayland?  So how does XWayland handle registering (wm-class) desktop files if its not the way 'skype' desktop file is using  'StartupWMClass=Skype'?

'I have tried swapping out the Exec line from skype to App Centre' Isn't that what that says?

"swapping out the Exec line from skype to App Centre" is the reverse of "changing the Exec line from App Centre to skype"
