Why does Kate install on Ubuntu 24.04 with a generic "gear" icon?
I have a ten year old laptop running Ubuntu 24.04.  I have installed the Kate application there and it comes with its own easily recognized icon. I use this a lot so I have it pinned to my dash. It was installed before I upgraded to 24.04.
Now I've purchased a new machine, also comes with Ubuntu 24.04. On it I also installed Kate.  It installed as a snap.  It has a generic "gear" icon that I don't like and can't change.
Why is this the case? Is this a result of it being installed as a snap?  Why isn't there an easy way to change the icon, or at least a way to do it through a config file?
Update:
After messing around for a couple hours, I am completely defeated.  The only way to install a usable kate on my machine seems to be through the Show Apps interface.  The App Center way is futile.  That produces the gear icon.  Trying to find a usable icon leads me down this rabbit hole:
$ which kate
/snap/bin/kate
$ ll /snap/bin/kate
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 26 13:09 /snap/bin/kate -> /usr/bin/snap*

I don't even know what the asterisk in this symbolic link means.  It doesn't lead me to any icons.  So I'm stuck with the gear. I can launch kate.  It works.  But why was this system released on the public before it was ready?
I know you guys don't like snark but is Ubuntu trying to repel its existing user base?

It's possible to extract the icon from a snap or appimage and make a proper desktop file to use it.  Sometimes snapd is able to do this, but depending on how the snap is constructed, it may not be able to do it automatically, but it should still be possible to manually do it. (ick)

Does the 'Kate' icon appear in the 'show apps' (bottom left) menu? If so right click on this and select 'append to dash'. Possibly, if successful you can now start it from the icon on the dash but the 'run' time icon will still appear as the gear. If so you might like to read the following question: -  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1533253/with-regard-to-desktop-skype-files-has-the-way-wm-class-changed-starting-with which  is the same thing for snap skype.

@user10489 ick is right.  Who asked for this?  I chose to get this computer with Ubuntu 24.04 preinstalled, since I was accustomed to it.  Oh well.

The icon thing is a messy long standing bug, but it's being worked on.  Problem is, container designs (like snap) bury the icon in the container, which is why you don't get one, so you need a tool to extract it into the external environment.  There's a disconnect between how the internal container and the external environment uses the icon (it's simple if there's no themes), so any tool to fix this is not going to be very portable.  And the containers are suppose to be portable...so fixing this is messy.

Remove the snap and install kate as a deb-package (sudo apt install kate).

@mook765 Oh, duh.  That still exists, who'd a thunk it.  I feel like an idiot.  Write it up as the answer and I'm happy to credit you.   The two GUI approaches suck compared to the apt method.  There are at least a few apps that cannot be installed this way, but apt should be the first resort if you want to avoid issues such as this.

Since Kate is part of the Plasma desktop used in Kubuntu, it still exists as a traditional deb-package in th official repositories.
You may want to remove the snap (snap remove kate) and install the deb package instead (sudo apt install kate).

So just to make sure I have this right, the trend is to move away from the previous proven reliable system in favor of two new systems, both of which have many issues.  Why?

@SteveCohen Many applications are nowadays available as snaps and also as deb-packages. Snaps have some advantages and some disadvantages, the same thing stands for deb-packages. The app center should show both of them. If there is a trend or not, I cannot really answer. See this nine years old question. Ubuntu hasn't really moved to snaps since, except some applications are now sanp only, e.g. Firefox, Thunderbird. but there are still ways to install these apps as traditional deb-packages.
